# SQL - Create accounting view table from 4 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

Stack Overflowers!

I have a problem creating a view table.

I would like to show the total amount by combining 4 tables.

Please help me!

---

### Table

[Table simple ERD image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THdHE.png)

```
Table users {
  id uuid [pk]
  username string
}

Table currencies {
  id uuid [pk]
  symbol string
 }

Table deposits {
  id uuid [pk]
  user_id uuid
  currency_id uuid
  amount decimal
}

Table withdraws {
  id uuid [pk]
  user_id uuid
  currency_id uuid
  amount decimal
}

Ref: users.id > deposits.user_id  
Ref: users.id > withdraws.user_id 
Ref: currencies.id > deposits.currency_id  
Ref: currencies.id > withdraws.currency_id
```

---

### Data

```
Table users {
  id | username
  a03c59e4-01ee-4e83-a0a9-1db671a3976c | John
  b8a118a7-6f59-497a-bfef-e7be1929d597 | Lucy
}

Table currencies {
  id | symbol
  c0586458-ffd6-4adb-b9ab-0ebd95233a4f | USD
  158db5bb-a701-4279-bcc0-3b04b57b9318 | JPY
}

Table deposits {
  id | user_id | currency_id | amount
  81422cfc-4abc-4380-98dc-315931a37d0f | a03c59e4-01ee-4e83-a0a9-1db671a3976c | c0586458-ffd6-4adb-b9ab-0ebd95233a4f | 100
}

Table withdraws {
  id | user_id | currency_id | amount
  7a628e19-d7eb-47c8-b6f5-73243f81186e | b8a118a7-6f59-497a-bfef-e7be1929d597 | 158db5bb-a701-4279-bcc0-3b04b57b9318 | 50
}
```

---

### Answer view table

```
Table positions {
  user_id | currency_id | total_deposit_amount | total_withdraw_amount
  a03c59e4-01ee-4e83-a0a9-1db671a3976c | c0586458-ffd6-4adb-b9ab-0ebd95233a4f | 100 | 0
  a03c59e4-01ee-4e83-a0a9-1db671a3976c | 158db5bb-a701-4279-bcc0-3b04b57b9318 | 0 | 0
  b8a118a7-6f59-497a-bfef-e7be1929d597 | c0586458-ffd6-4adb-b9ab-0ebd95233a4f | 0 | 0
  b8a118a7-6f59-497a-bfef-e7be1929d597 | 158db5bb-a701-4279-bcc0-3b04b57b9318 | 0 | 50
}
```

The positions view table must show all user_id and currency_id,

If there is no amount in the deposits, withdraws table, it is displayed as 0 in positions.

---

### Tried my solution

SQL code

```
SELECT d.user_id user_id, d.currency_id currency_id, SUM(d.amount) total_deposit_amount
FROM deposits d
GROUP BY d.user_id, d.currency_id
```

Result

This solution print only exist deposit.

1. I want to print a total amount field **each users and currencies**.
2. I want to combine **deposits and withdraws** table.

---

Comment: What you try to solve the problem

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev I had edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First combine `deposits` and `withdraws` into a single result set using `union all`.

When you have that, then you can use `sum()` aggregation grouping on `user_id` and `currency_id` to get your answer.

```
with combined as (
  select user_id, currency_id, amount as deposit_amount, 0 as withdraw_amount
    from deposits
  union all
  select user_id, currency_id, 0 as deposit_amount, amount as withdraw_amount
    from withdraws
)
select users.id as user_id, currencies.id as currency_id,
       coalesce(sum(combined.deposit_amount), 0) as total_deposit_amount,
       coalesce(sum(combined.withdraw_amount), 0) as total_withdraw_amount
  from users
       cross join currencies
       left join combined
              on combined.user_id = users.id
             and combined.currency_id = currencies.id
 group by users.id, currencies.id;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mike too! I need to study more. You are a true master in SQL.

Comment: This is not how I would approach the problem but at least it is a very reasonable solution and should produce the correct answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Hmm, given the OP's example the CTE will have two rows. Then an aggregation is done over it. Hence the result in the end can have a maximum of two rows either. But the OP's desired result has four rows. How is that the correct answer then, or where am I wrong?

Comment: @GordonLinoff
This answer does''t output the information I want.
I want the result of all combinations of user_id and currentcy_id.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You're God of SQL... I want to know about your approach.